# Use inbuilt SQLserver from visual studio-2008

Tags: vb.net

I am going to start project in VB.net using MSV.Studio-2008. In that I want to use sql server that is provided with MS visual studio. How can I use it and how can I create database in that server. I dont have any separate sql server installed in my PC except provided my visual studio-2008. Is it possible to use it???
Please guide me how to start with and how to make connection in such case???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download SQL Express from http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx
It includes SQL Server Management Studio which makes it easier to create and manipulate databases. The "built-in" SQL instance, if it's installed, can be connected to as .\SQLEXPRESS by default.